# How to search and replace using hash with Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I'm new to Perl and I'm afraid I am stuck and wanted to ask if someone might be able to help me.

I have a file with two columns (tab separated) of oldname and newname.

I would like to use the oldname as key and newname as value and store it as a hash.

Then I would like to open a different file (gff file) and replace all the oldnames in there with the newnames and write it to another file.

I have given it my best try but am getting a lot of errors.

If you could let me know what I am doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here are how the two files look:

oldname newname(SFXXXX) file:

```
genemark-scaffold00013-abinit-gene-0.18 SF130001
augustus-scaffold00013-abinit-gene-1.24 SF130002
genemark-scaffold00013-abinit-gene-1.65 SF130003
```

file to search and replace in (an example of one of the lines):

```
scaffold00013   maker   gene    258253  258759  .   -   .   ID=maker-scaffold00013-augustus-gene-2.187;Name=maker-scaffold00013-augustus-gene-2.187;
```

Here is my attempt:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $hashfile = $ARGV[0];
my $gfffile  = $ARGV[1];
my %names;
my $oldname;
my $newname;

if (!defined $hashfile) {
    die "Usage: $0 hash_file gff_file\n";
}

if (!defined $gfffile) {
    die "Usage: $0 hash_file gff_file\n";
}

###save hashfile with two columns, oldname and newname, into a hash with oldname as key and newname as value.

open(HFILE, $hashfile) or die "Cannot open $hashfile\n";

while (my $line = <HFILE>) {
    chomp($line);
    my ($oldname, $newname) = split /\t/;
    $names{$oldname} = $newname;
}

close HFILE;

###open gff file and replace all oldnames with newnames from %names.

open(GFILE, $gfffile) or die "Cannot open $gfffile\n";

while (my $line2 = <GFILE>) {
    chomp($line2);

    eval "$line2 =~ s/$oldname/$names{oldname}/g";

    open(OUT, ">SFrenamed.gff") or die "Cannot open SFrenamed.gff: $!";

    print OUT "$line2\n";

    close OUT;
}

close GFILE;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is that you aren't splitting the `$line` variable. `split /\t/` splits `$_` by default, and you haven't put anything in there.

This program builds the hash, and then constructs a regex from all the keys by sorting them in descending order of length and joining them with the `|` regex alternation operator. The sorting is necessary so that the *longest* of all possible choices is selected if there are any alternatives.

Every occurrence of the regex is replaced by the corresponding new name in each line of the input file, and the output written to the new file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

die "Usage: $0 hash_file gff_file\n" if @ARGV < 2;

my ($hashfile, $gfffile) = @ARGV;

open(my $hfile, '<', $hashfile) or die "Cannot open $hashfile: $!";
my %names;
while (my $line = <$hfile>) {
    chomp($line);
    my ($oldname, $newname) = split /\t/, $line;
    $names{$oldname} = $newname;
}
close $hfile;

my $regex = join '|', sort { length $b <=> length $a } keys %names;
$regex = qr/$regex/;

open(my $gfile, '<', $gfffile) or die "Cannot open $gfffile: $!";
open(my $out, '>', 'SFrenamed.gff') or die "Cannot open SFrenamed.gff: $!";

while (my $line = <$gfile>) {
    chomp($line);
    $line =~ s/($regex)/$names{$1}/g;
    print $out $line, "\n";
}

close $out;
close $gfile;
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for pointing that out and correcting it!  I guess I didn't even think of the sorting part and now the split part makes sense...Looks like I have a long ways to learn but will keep at it.  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry to ask again as the script above did not work and is giving me the original gff file with certain lines deleted and I am not sure what is going on...maybe it is because I didn't clarify enough.  I want to replace the part after ID= and Name= with its corresponding SFXXXXX instead of the 'maker-scaffold00013-augustus-gene-2.187' values.  So in each line there can be multiple replacements and there can be multiple rows with the same key as well (all keys and values are unique as long as the whole length of the key can be matched).

Comment: @user2278592: Then I suspect that your `hash_file` *isn't* tab-separated. The data you have posted in your question has no tabs in it. Try replacing `/\t/` with `' '` and see if that works for you. If you are using space as a separator then there can be no spaces in the names, is that OK?

Comment: Yes, so sorry I did not check that, that was my problem!..how embarrassing...and thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using an eval? And `$oldname` is going to be undefined in the second while loop, because the first while loop you redeclare them in that scope (even if you used the outer scope, it would store the very last value that you processed, which wouldn't be helpful).

Take out the `my $oldname` and `my $newname` at the top of your script, it is useless.

Take out the entire `eva`l line. You need to repeat the regex for each thing you want to replace. Try something like:

```
$line2 =~ s/$_/$names{$_}/g for keys %names;
```

Also see Borodin's answer. He made one big regex instead of a loop, and caught your lack of the second argument to split.

Comment: To be honest I don't know eval but I saw some post somewhere and mistook that that was what I was supposed to do...but I see now that I didn't need it, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: How do I redefine the $oldname and $newname in the second while loop or is that not necessary with $line2 =~ s/$_/$names{$_}/g for keys %names ?

Comment: The `for keys %names` will iterate through the hashkeys of `%names`, executing `$line2 =~ s/$_/$names{$_}/g` once for each key, where `$_` (the loop variable) contains the key and of course `$names{$_}` is the corresponding value. The $oldname and $newname, because of the keyword `my`, go out of scope at the end of the block (nearest right-curly-brace). In the first while, you're taking $oldname and $newname and storing them in the %names hash ($oldname as the key and $newname as the value) so they are not needed again, all your data is in the %names hash.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  For some reason it is still not working and now it gives me lines in which the keys are not replaced and the problem is all the lines are reshuffled.  Do I need to split $line2 at ';' because my keys are embedded with characters on both sides and is not separated by white space?  please let me know if my description is not clear.

Comment: In your example, the keys will contain strings such as `genemark-scaffold00013-abinit-gene-0.18`. The second while loop will look for `genemark-scaffold00013-abinit-gene-0.18` and replace it with `SF130001`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, that it right :)!!  I change my original script as you advised (got rid of my $oldname and my $newname, split /\t/,$line; as Borodin advised, and replaced the eval with $line2 =~ s/$_/$names{$_}/g for keys %names;)....Is it because the string I want to replace is after ID= or Name= and is not separated by white space?  Or maybe I'm totally off...